# Problem relate to Row$A=(Nul A)^⊥$

Tags: linear-algebra

$x$ is in $Null A$,

so $Ax=0$

and   $ x dot y=0$
the above two condition is given 
how to prove that  y is in Row A?

Just think about the problem of Row $A=(Nul A)^⊥$
i can infer that    if $x$ belongs to Row A,  x will belongs to $(Nul A^)⊥$ 
but how to infer if x belongs to $(Nul A^)⊥$, x will belongs to Row A?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $y\cdot x=0$ for all $x$ in the null space of $A$. Then if we add to $A$ the new row $y$, call this $B$ we see that this has the same null space as $A$. This means that 
$$rank A=rank B$$ and thus the new row is a combination of the rows of $A$.

Comment: sorry,   sir            Ax=0                y⋅x=0 for any x in null space of A (ker A) ,     you mean we can put y as a row vector in the bottom of A?

Comment: But why when y is added to A  , the row vector start to be linearly dependent , so we can conclude that y is  linear combination of row vector of A?

Comment: I answered this 5 days ago, NOW you are asking a question ?

Comment: Just not too clear,  would you kindly explain a bit further ?